# AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver (snd_hda_intel) is recognized, but no sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have an ASUS laptop with Xubuntu Linux 22.04 installed. The audio device is recognized by the system and I can see indicator moving when playing something, but unfortunately there is no audible sound from the speakers. It works OK in Windows though, or with USB headphones.

```
# inxi -SMA
System:
  Host: Kernel: 6.5.0-26-generic x86_64 bits: 64
    Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: ROG Strix G733PYV_G733PYV v: 1.0
  Mobo: ASUSTeK model: G733PYV v: 1.0
    UEFI: American Megatrends LLC. v: G733PYV.327 date: 08/23/2023
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-2: AMD Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
    driver: snd_rpl_pci_acp6x
  Device-3: AMD Family 17h HD Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
  Device-4: GN Netcom Jabra Link 380 type: USB
    driver: jabra,snd-usb-audio,usbhid
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.5.0-26-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

I've tried various audio fixing guides online, but nothing seems to help.

What could be done about that? I will be glad to provide any relevant information on request, thanks.